# How to create Path instance in Kotlin (JDK 8)?

Tags: kotlin, java-8, path

How to create a `java.nio.file.Path` instance in Kotlin?

Env: JDK 8, Kotlin 1.6.10

Usual construction `Path.of` does not compile.

This file is not compilable (error = `Unresolved reference: of`)

```
package com.myproject.toolbox

import java.nio.file.Path

fun y(): Path {
    return Path.of("abc")
}
```

> On JDK 11+ the problem does not exist.

Comment: That function wasn't added until after Java 8. It's a convenience function that does the same thing as `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath()`

Comment: [`Paths.get(String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-), mind the `s` in `Paths`.